# Django REST Framework - method patch not allowed with UpdateModelMixin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to update a record in my database with the REST framework. I'm getting an message of method not allowed for anything but "GET".

views.py

```
class MetadataViewTest(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                    generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = deployment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SerializerTest

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('api/metadata_test/<int:pk>/', views.MetadataViewTest.as_view())
]
```

serializers.py

```
class SerializerTest(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = deployment
        fields = [field.name for field in deployment._meta.fields]
```

I've tried the request through postman as a PATCH PUT or POST at api/metadata_test/20/

This is a simplified version, I plan on overriding the get put and delete functions.

Comment: You might be using the wrong URL

Comment: @JPG That's what I was thinking, but can't figure it out

Comment: @MilonMahato I tried viewsets.GenericViewSet with a router and that also does not work. Not sure what resumeonlivre_rest is

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to:

views.py

```
class MetadataViewTest(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    queryset = deployment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SerializerTest
```

urls.py

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('api/metadata_test/', views.MetadataViewTest.as_view()) # Should to the list, not detail
]
```

Call API like this `PUT/PATCH: api/metadata_test/20/`

---

It better if you use `viewsets.GenericViewSet` instead of `generics.GenericAPIView` because you are using `...ModelMixin`.

Your router like this

```
from rest_framework import routers


api_router = routers.DefaultRouter()

api_router.register('metadata_test', MetadataViewTest, basename='metadata_test')
...
```

Comment: I am still getting the error "Method not allowed" on both these solutions.

Comment: @R.Anderson Can you update to `class MetadataViewTest(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView): ...`

Comment: I tried changing it to MetadataViewTest(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView) that did not fix it.

Comment: I believe I found the issue. It was getting routed to another class, I changed the URL pattern. It was going to 'api/metadata'. I didn't realize it matched that one first.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is instead of calling /api/metadata_test/ call /api/metadata_test/**12345**/

Where **12345** is the id/pk of the record. I am assuming that id is the primary key of the model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).